# Any data on how often trickbot communicates with certain IPs

Tags: malware

I notice on various documents involving the Trickbot malware, they all state that trickbot determines the infected host's external IP address by communicating with the following hosts:

```
hxxp://myexternalip.com/raw
hxxp://api.ipify.org
hxxp://icanhazip.com
hxxp://bot.whatismyipaddress.com
hxxp://ip.anysrc.net/plain/clientip
```

I have been unable to find any data on how often or when this communication with these hosts takes place. Does it take place only once during the initial infection, or does it recur at standard or random intervals after the initial infection?

Comment: ... probably on the schedule set up when it sets itself up in the Scheduled Task ... (i.e. every 10 minutes)